# Calculating roller coaster loops - how to get x and y in terms of s?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[In this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4q2W5SJc5j4) the author presents a method to calculate shapes of roller coaster loops. At 13:20, three differential equations are presented to plot the shape of a loop providing a constant force $G$ for an initial velocity $v_0$:

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial s} &= \frac{G-g\cos\left(\theta\right)}{v_0^2-2gy} \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} &= \cos\theta \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} &= \sin\theta
\end{align}$

where $g$ is acceleration due to gravity, $9.80665~\text{m}/\text{s}^2$.

I would like to eliminate the need for the $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial s}$ term. Do I integrate both sides of all these equations with respect to $s$ and then substitute $\theta$ in for the $x$ and $y$ equations, or am I stuck with three equations?

Another problem is that the first equation has $\theta$ and $y$ on the right side, so how would I proceed?

Comment: The unknown functions $\theta(s)$ and $y(s)$ both appear on the right-hand side of that first equation (the former composed with $\cos$ no less), so you might have some trouble integrating it directly.

Answer (score 0):

if you use $\delta s = \delta y \sqrt{1+(\tan \theta)^{-2}}$ that changes first equation to 
$$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y} = \frac{G-g\cos\left(\theta\right)}{(v_0^2-2gy)\sqrt{1+(\tan \theta)^{-2}}}$$

this allows you to separate all theta terms to one size and all y terms to the other

$$\partial\theta\frac{ 2\csc \theta }{\cos\theta-G/g} = \frac{\partial y}{(y-v_0^2/2g)}$$

now you integrate

$$2\int_0^{\theta} \frac{ \csc \phi}{\cos\phi-G/g} d\phi = \int_0^y\frac{dz}{(z-v_0^2/2g)}$$

RHS is $$\ln\left((1-\frac{2gy}{v_0^2})\right)$$

and LHS comes out to be

$$\ln \left[ \left(1-\cos \theta \right)^\frac{1}{1-G/g}  \left( \cos \theta +1 \right) ^\frac{1}{1+G/g} \left( \cos \theta - G/g \right) ^ {\frac{2}{(G/g)^2-1}}\right]$$

exponentiation of both sides

$$ y=v_0^2 /2g\left[1-\left(1-\cos \theta \right)^\frac{1}{1-G/g}  \left( \cos \theta +1 \right) ^\frac{1}{1+G/g} \left( \cos \theta - G/g \right) ^ {\frac{2}{(G/g)^2-1}}\right]$$

Comment: Very cool technique!  I don't want to upvote because I don't believe I can give a well-enough informed opinion on the validity of all the steps.  I hope others will be able to check it.

Comment: Are you using $ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} $ ?

Comment: used that the incremental path length differential $\delta s$ is equal to square root of sum of squares of differential increments along $y$-direction and along $x$-direction ... then just factor out a $\delta y$

Comment: i think your "very cool technique" comment is all the upvote i needed

Comment: @JakeMirra or the $\delta s = \delta y \sqrt{1+(\tan \theta)^{-2}}$ equation comes from OP equation 2 squared plus equation 3 squared ... this concept is key for path integrals and calculus of variations

Comment: So does $\sqrt{1+\left(\tan\theta\right)^{-2}}$ degenerate to $\csc\theta$?

Comment: @ElEctric yes ... made edits to answer to incorporate this (and other) simplification

Comment: Just curious about this, but what would $x$ be as a function of $\theta$?

Comment: due to conservation of energy, $y(\theta)$ directly gives you $\frac{ds}{dt}(\theta)=\sqrt {(v_0^2+2gy(\theta))}$ which then will uniquely determine $x(\theta)$